# ASP.net core 3.0 GET Method with %2B in query parameter not working on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have a very strange issue with an asp.net core 3.0 api that works fine on my machine, but it doesn't work on Azure in a specific case.

Let's say we have this route and both my machine and the azure web app are querying the same database with the exact same code:

```
/api/employees/{email}
```

If I use an existing email ie: **j.doe@mail.com** this works on my machine and Azure with this response:

```
{
    "employeeId": "12904a63-94b5-411a-87bc-07bb2d2de4f0",
    "lastName": "John",
    "firstName": "Doe",
    "email": "j.doe@mail.com"
}
```

Now if I try this email **jane.doe@mail.com** this user doesn't exist in my database and I have this 404 message on my machine and Azure:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4",
    "title": "Not Found",
    "status": 404,
    "traceId": "00-b8cbc03357fc564bb22dc6ff231336ef-e10fac745a531549-00"
}
```

Things are getting strange now:

I have this email address **jane.doe+test@mail.com** which exists in my database:

On my machine I have this result:

```
{
    "employeeId": "4569bc34-94b5-411a-87bc-07bb2d2de4f0",
    "lastName": "Jane",
    "firstName": "Doe",
    "email": "jane.doe+test@mail.com"
}
```

On azure I have this 404 error

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Turning on logs on azure web app I have this trace:

```
2019-12-09 14:48:13 MYAPI-QA GET /api/employees/jane.doe+test@mail.com X-ARR-LOG-ID=8c3956c0-3dba-46e5-a292-7b59facfc7ce 443 - 1.1.1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:71.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/71.0 ARRAffinity=;+AppServiceAuthSession= - myapi.azurewebsites.net 404 11 0 433 2335 79
```

My webapi is not writing logs and it looks like this 404 message is not coming from my webapi at all...

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? I am having same issue with routes that include %2B

Comment: the model binding seems to be converting %2B into a space rather than + or at least it is double escaping it. "this+is+a+string" comes from "this is a string" in a url. But when a + is intended as a plus it seems to double resolve it. I pass "qu%2B9I" in url and it binds to a string variable containing "qu 9l". Now to work out why

Comment: Just to follow up my prev comment. It must be vue/nuxt changing it in some way. Calling the get api method directly worked as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I finally found my problem.

The code was working on my machine because I was using kestrel.
Running the same code with IIS didn't work with this error:

```
HTTP Error 404.11 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.
```

To solve this, I had to add a web.config file with this inside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"/>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```